# Retrospectively add a master branch to my GitHub repo

Tags: git, github, branch, git-branch

I created a GitHub repo and I think my first commit must have been to a development branch I created. Lets call it `foo`.

Now the only branch in my remote is `foo`. I have no `master`. Is there any way I can retrospectively create a `master` branch without the entire commit history of `foo`? I was thinking about creating a local branch called `master` and delete all commits except for my first commit. Would that work? Also, if this is an option will master instinctively become the default or would I need to set thatsomewhere?

Comment: If you want to get rid of all your history, why not simply recreating the repo?

Comment: Unless you create a branch called development, the first commit will always be on master.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing `git checkout -b master <commit sha>`

Answer (score 0):

In your situation I'll do:

1. checkout from foo as master `git checkout -b master`
2. then reset to the timestamp of history where master should be `git reset --hard {dst_commit}`
3. now push your local master branch to remote `git push origin master`

Does this solution suit your problem?

Comment: I think so. Just one more question. Will this become my master branch by default or will I have to set this oin some way?

Comment: What do you mean? Check this https://help.github.com/articles/setting-the-default-branch/

Comment: If you did this, check local file .git/config . I've never used it but I'm curious that help.

Comment: @runnerpaul `git rest --hard` flag will move the master branch label to whatever commit you give the reference for.

Comment: It turns out that won't work for me. If I could squash all commits on my `foo` branch into a single commit and rename that to master I'd be OK. If that's possible I'd hopefully be able to rename the commit also. Can that be done?